# hr_timesheet_time_sheet: Field res.company.sheet_range with non-str value in selection

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-14

During install of the hr_timesheet_time_sheet module in Odoo 14 community edition, the stacktrace below is produced. This is related to recent changes in Odoo 14 handling of the Selection field # and #.

AssertionError: Field res.company.sheet_range with non-str value in selection

Comment: Please provide a link to the module you installed.

Comment: https://github.com/OCA/timesheet/tree/11.0/hr_timesheet_sheet  From this folder i just add it into the version 14 addons. while installing this module i am getting this type of error as AssertionError: Field res.company.sheet_range with non-str value in selection

Comment: from odoo import fields, models
from dateutil.rrule import (MONTHLY, WEEKLY, DAILY)

_WEEKDAYS = [
    ('0', 'Monday'),
    ('1', 'Tuesday'),
    ('2', 'Wednesday'),
    ('3', 'Thursday'),
    ('4', 'Friday'),
    ('5', 'Saturday'),
    ('6', 'Sunday')
]


class ResCompany(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.company'

    sheet_range = fields.Selection([
        (MONTHLY, 'Month'),
        (WEEKLY, 'Week'),
        (DAILY, 'Day')],
        string='Timesheet Sheet Range',
        default=WEEKLY,
        help="The range of your Timesheet Sheet.")

Comment: timesheet_week_start = fields.Selection(
        selection=_WEEKDAYS,
        string='Week start day',
        default='0')
From this code i am getting such type of an error

Comment: You try to install an Odoo-11 module on Odoo-14, you may get errors as there are many changes in Odoo. You need  to migrate the code from Odoo-11 to Odoo-14, you can try the [OCA guidelines](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-12.0)